# How to deploy a WebApp from a folder (not a zip) in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

I cannot get DevOps to deploy using a folder, it is giving me this error:

> [error]Error: No package found with specified pattern:
>   d:\a\1\a*.deploy.cmd
> Check if the package mentioned in the task
>   is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and
>   downloaded in the current job.

Azure App Service Deploy Task documentation says this about the Package argument:

> File path to the package, or to a folder containing App Service
>   contents generated by MSBuild, or to a compressed zip or war file.

this is my publish task:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: false
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: true
      projects: |
        src/Company/Project.csproj
```

and my deploy task:

```
  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'PublishProfile'
      PublishProfilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Company/Properties/PublishProfiles/WebDeploy.pubxml'
      PublishProfilePassword: '$(password)'
      Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Company'
```

Why is it looking for a deploy.cmd? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More then a year later, have you managed to work your way around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\1\a*.deploy.cmd

From the error message, the root cause of this issue could be that there is no such file(xxx.deploy.cmd) in your path.

The "Dotnet Publish" task will not produce this file.

To solve this issue, you need to add a **"Dotnet build" task** . This task will generate the necessary files (e.g. deploy.cmd):

At the same time, you also need to add configuration parameters in the **arguments** field.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

Here is an example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
....
```

Then the xxx.deploy.cmd will be added.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: does adding /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true make it deploy a zip instead though? And is the publish command even necessary then?

Comment: If you look at my publish task, that is exactly what I'm doing. The issue is that "AzureRmWebAppDeployment" fails trying to deploy the folder. Is this not actually supported?

Comment: From this doc about [azure app service deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops):"package: a folder containing App Service contents generated by MSBuild". The folder is supported by the task. But the necessary configuration files need to be included in the artifacts folder (e.g. deploy.cmd file).

Comment: MsDeploy is capable of deploying a folder without the cmd file though, it does it when you publish with visual studio. This is also [not how it's documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#package-and-deliver-your-code)

Comment: According to your requirements, I suggestion that you could use the **"ConnectionType:AzureRM"** (Azure Resource Manager) . In this case, the default deploy method is **web deploy**. You could try to directly deploy the folder to webapp. Please test it and check if it could work. If it needs to deploy. cmd file by default,  the deployment method could be zip deploy.

Comment: How if I can't connect to azure web app through resource manager?
I set the path correctly but it still complain about can't find that .deploy.cmd

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```yaml
  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
    inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'PublishProfile'
      PublishProfilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Company/Properties/PublishProfiles/WebDeploy.pubxml'
      PublishProfilePassword: '$(password)'
      Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Company/*'
```

The difference is in `Package` input.

Comment: Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: d:\a\1\a\Company\*. Please restrain the search pattern. Do I need to point it at a .dll?